# Will a transformer work without two separate cylinders?

Tags: transformer, design

A transformer has two inductors. When one of the inductors is fed AC, a changing magnetic field is produced. This is because the magnetic flux can penetrate through the transformer core and induce a voltage in the secondary coil.

The standard design is to have a rectangle shape with the coils on opposite sides. Since a transformer works through the magnetic flux penetrating the core, that should mean that any design where the magnetic flux penetrates the core and can induce a voltage in the secondary coil, any design that satisfies that should work.

Accounting for that, does that mean I could take a simple iron cylinder, wrap a wire a few times at one end, then wrap a wire a different number of times at the other end, and still have a working transformer?

Something like:

[image]

source: me

Could this design be extended so ANY shared magnetic material will make a transformer?

Comment: It would definitely work to some extent, but the performance would be worse. Someone who knows more would have to tell you exactly how.

Comment: The magnetic path needs a closed circuit. An air core transformer of one that requires the flux to travel out one end of a rod and go through air to get to the other end would not perform as well for power and audio frequencies.

Comment: That *rectangley shape* is the conductor for flux.  Majority of flux will stay inside *rectangley shape*, linking secondary to primary.  Majority of your flux must pass through air, which resists the flow of flux.

Comment: Voltage is induced; not current.

Comment: The two coils structure reminds me of: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Ferrite_antenna.jpg?1628239751690 although that's an antenna not a transformer and the core is ferrite (powdered iron glued together) not solid iron.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat yeah I originally thought that since my design had an iron path between the conductors, it would still work. I really need to learn more about magnetism.

Comment: @Andyaka good point, I was using terms loosely but I will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, yes. Just not very well ([Toonces the cat?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fvsItXYgzk)). There are a lot of different shapes for transformer cores.  All of them are attempting to capture the magnetic fields and keep them in the core. As new ideas come along and new products need different geometries (usually smaller and smaller), the core manufactures create new shapes and sizes (and materials and construction) to meet those new requirements.

Like a magnet, the field lines must go from the "North" side back around to the "South" side, in a loop.  Adding the metal core as you have drawn it will pull those field lines in towards the core, but it will not help them reach around to the other end.

This image shows an example of how the magnetic flux flows through the metal core.
[image]

No matter the shape, there should always be a circular path for the magnetic flux through the transformer core from "North" to "South":
[image]

Images from [electricaleasy.com](https://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/03/electrical-transformer-basic.html)

Comment: +1,Is there any Mathematical way to precisely calculate the magnetic field  intensity in the core of any ferromagnetic material of any shape?

Comment: My design was due to a misconception of how a transformer works - I thought simply putting a straight path between the coils was enough. 

"Like a magnet, the field lines must go from the "North" side back around to the "South" side, in a loop." So, this means that the core simply contains the lines, and then the field will no longer be the usual shape but rather a rectangular shape with one side being the coil, apart from leakage, correct? And the voltage in the secondary coil is induced due to the changing magnetic field going through it?

Comment: Think about it like an onion.  Each field line is a three dimensional shape.  They can be compressed but they cannot touch.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the magnetic lines of flux that are produced when applying a primary voltage (flux lines shown in orange below): -

[image]

So, when you apply an AC voltage to the primary, only a fraction of the magnetic flux lines produced will "couple" with "some" of the secondary winding turns. This means that: -

- You cannot rely on the turns ratio for predicting the input-output voltage ratio any more
- There are inductances in both primary and secondary that are just not coupled to each other (they don't share the same flux)
- These are called leakage inductances and can be regarded as separate circuit entities
- Any current you try and draw from the secondary winding will flow through those leakage inductances and produce volt drops

Hence, not only cannot you rely on the turns ratio for predicting the output voltage on the secondary but, if you drive current into a load on the secondary that unreliable voltage ratio is made even more unreliable.

> *This is because the magnetic flux can penetrate through the
> transformer core and induce a current in the secondary coil.*

**Voltage** is induced. Current flows when a load is connected. Current is **not** induced.

> *does that mean I could take a simple iron cylinder, wrap a wire a few times at one end, then wrap a wire a different number of times at the other end, and still have a working transformer?*

It's a transformer in a loose sense but, it's not a good transformer for many, many applications. Additionally, the solid iron core acts as a partial shorted turn and you will have significant losses as well as all the other problems I mentioned.

[image]

It won't happen because there is a massive air-gap. On the other hand, it **will happen** (circa 95% to 99%) on a fully enclosing magnetic core that has a decent level of magnetic permeability.

Comment: "Voltage is induced. Current flows when a load is connected. Current is not induced." Good catch, I edited the question.

[Placeholder text, symbolic link to my comment on Aaron's answer]

Could you answer these questions?

Comment: @AgnivaChaudhuri I have no idea what that link is meant to do - i.e. it doesn't work. If you want extra questions answered (as a follow-up to your main question) please state them clearly and be brief. This is a Q and A site and not a continuous-learning forum where a question might be developed due to comments. Your original question appears to be answered so, additional questions should be for clarification only.

Comment: sorry about that, I was in a rush and didn't want to type that again :) I couldn't figure out how to hyperlink to a comment so I thought I could redirect you to my answer on Aaron's comment so you could hopefully answer those clarification questions. My clarification questions are: in a working transformer, are the field lines no longer like a standard magnet, but instead in a rectangle shape going between the inductors?  And is voltage induced because of these changing field lines in the inductor core?

Comment: @AgnivaChaudhuri if you took four bar magnets and arranged them into a square (->NS-->NS-->NS-->NS->), the field lines would be internal changing 90 degrees at each point that two magnets touched. The same is true for a full core on a transformer AND they will (mainly) go inside each winding thus, field lines from primary mainly intersect with secondary. Voltage is induced due to the changing magnetic field (as symbolized by the field line density changing).