# Can steel nails be substituted for the silicon steel laminate in a motor/generator/alternator?

Tags: electromagnetism, wiring, wire, generator, alternator

This is as diagram of a generator/alternator in which steel nails are used in place of silicon steel laminates:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Define “can”. Will it give any measurable effect? Yes. Is it a good idea? No.

Comment: It also depends on the direction your nails are wrapped.  And the number of turns.  And the current.  OK for proof of concept.

Comment: See also this question for information about the magnetic fields: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580397/will-a-transformer-work-without-two-separate-cylinders/

Comment: Steel (iron) is a good conductor for flux.  Air is a poor conductor for flux and it should be minimized.  Steel will concentrate and shape your magnetic field.  The large airgap between the nails means the flux produced by the coil arround the nails will mostly pass through air and be weakened.

Comment: Normal steel has high retentivity (residual magnetism when the field is removed). Not the best when you're trying to alternate the magnetic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very much depends why you are doing this. If for a demonstration of the principle, then fine. If you are making any attempt at a practical generator with reasonable output and efficiency, then forget it.

There are two different things at play here, the material, and the shape.

The material. Steel nails aren't too bad as a core material. They are magnetically 'harder' than the ideal steel for laminations, so will have higher hysteresis losses than proper iron.

The shape. The nails are only filling about 50% of the length of the air-gap around your rotor, so will only give you twice the field that you would have had with an air-core. You could leave them out completely and use a stronger rotor magnet. There are some commercial motors and alternators built with strong magnets and air cores for lightness and simplicity, albeit with low power densities.

If you look at the diagrams of motors and alternators, it's very easy to miss the return path round the outside of the coil cores, thinking it's just the case of the motor, the one that you've not drawn on your diagram. This is air at the moment, and responsible for your nails only giving you a 2:1 improvement in field. You need to put a return path that magnetically connects all the sharp ends of the nails. Nails don't have the ideal shape to make a good connection, but if you can fill most of this air length with steel, you'll get a further perhaps two-fold improvement in field.

Comment: You can also buy differently shaped pieces of steel without that shape problem, perhaps long thick rods (which you'd have to cut), or bolts.

Comment: The shape problem can  largely be solved by a ring shaped bundle of nails round the outer perimeter, as close as you can get to all those nail points.